# Grunt server autoprefixer errir

Tags: gruntjs

I have been developing a web app and using the grunt server that came with Yeoman. However for no reason, when I went to run it today I was presented with this error:

```
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...ERROR
Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp" file (EACCES, permission denied '.tmp/styles'). Use --force to continue.
```

How do I go about resolving this error?

Comment: Does the user you're running grunt as have access to `.tmp/styles`?

Comment: ive run it under sudo, nut i dont know how to check access for that file